# To resolve PDO NULL issue, change field to NULL in PHPMyAdmin or check for NULL in code and if so, set to empty string?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

My PHP website has a form that inserts data into mysql using PDO.  For example, one of the fields on the form is "email".

It's NOT required.  So on submit, I set the email variable before inserting using:

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
```

Then I insert using PDO prepared statement. Before, when using mysqli to insert, it would insert as blank no problem.  But now with PDO, if they leave it blank it's causing:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null in...
```

I researched and it seems PDO won't allow NULL Values to be inserted unless MySQL is told it can receive them.  So it seems like I have two options...

```
1.  In MySQL (via PHPMyAdmin), check the "Null" checkbox for that column under "Structure"
2.  In the code, add a small snippet like this:

if (empty($email)) {
$email="";  //set it equal to blank, which allows it to get inserted into the database without needing to mark the field as NULL in MySQL
}
```

I'm wondering what the advantages/disadvantages are to either option #1 or #2?  I sometimes might have lots of form options that COULD be left blank, so in that regard, #2 could be a lot more work adding the `if (empty())` snippet for ALL of them.

So is #1 the best bet?

Or is there another option I'm missing?

Comment: if the null value is allowe then you should change your table constraints ..

Comment: If you allow empty values then just set it to be nullable. It won't bother you on output as `<div class="email"><?= $user->email ?></div>` will still appear as an empty string

Comment: The message states that is your **database** and not PDO that does not allow null values. Before inserting your email, try to `var_dump( $email ); die();` your variable to see if indeed it is set to null or no.

Comment: @Anwar Nairi, what's weird is that before I converted to PDO (was using mysqli with exaxt same database structure), the database would accept the empty $email field.  So maybe it's just that PDO is stricter or something? Not really sure.

Comment: When editing the field in the Structure tab, look for the "NULL" checkbox. When un-checked, this is the equivalent of the NOT NULL statement.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is from the database, not PDO, PDO is just a way of accessing the DB.

Back to your question, the obvious answer is that if you have an optional field in your application, you should set its column to be nullable.

If you choose the other option, which is :

```
if (empty($email)) {
   $email="";  
}
```

I'm not going to say it's bad, but just imagine that at some point you needed to add more fields to your application, and the majority of them are optional, are you going to do that nullability test for each one them?

I wouldn't do it if I were you.

Comment: Thank you.  Is that a general rule of thumb, i.e. that ALL fields in a database that are optional should be set to be NULLABLE?

Answer (score 0):

You should always be validating every field submitted to your application. Not only to ensure that each entry conforms to the database integrity, but to help prevent SQL Injection (PDO also greatly helps with that) cross-site scripting and even the validity of the data. While the email address might be optional, why not still make sure that someone provided a properly formatted email address and that there are no extraneous characters (like spaces) in the input?

For example:

```
if( empty( $_POST["email"] ) )
{
    $email = "";
} else
{
    $email = strtolower( cleanInput( $_POST["email"] ) );

    // check if e-mail address syntax is valid or not
    if ( !preg_match( "/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/", $email ) )
    {
        $emailError = "Invalid email format";
    }
}

/*
* Function to clean input prior to processing
*/
function cleanInput( $data )
{
    $data = trim( $data );
    $data = stripslashes( $data );
    $data = htmlspecialchars( $data );
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be stripping slashes nor escaping HTML in the validation. Instead, use prepared statements and only escape when you are outputting, respectively.

Comment: @Mikey Depends on the case. This is just an example. `stripslashes()` helps prevent issues for those systems that still have that set as a default and depending on the field, `htmlspecialchars()` can be a way of preventing XSS. You can also choose to put the XSS protections on the output depending on your application.

Comment: `some\one@address.com` is not a valid email but would pass your validation. If they are putting slashes and/or HTML code, then it's a bad email.

Comment: @Mikey Good point. That's what I get for a quick one off the cuff. Made it a bit more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: This PDO insert statement should work with NULL values:

```
$row = [
    'email' => $_POST['email']
];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users SET email=:email;";
$status = $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($row);

if ($status) {
    echo "OK";
}
```

**Option 2**: Auto detection of the correct PDO datatype parameter.

```
function get_pdo_type($value)
{
    switch (true) {
        case is_bool($value):
            $dataType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            break;
        case is_int($value):
            $dataType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            break;
        case is_null($value):
            $dataType = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            break;
        default:
            $dataType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }
    return $dataType;
}

// Usage
$email = $_POST['email'];

$pdo = new PDO('dsn', 'username', 'password');
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET email=:email;';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, get_pdo_type($email));
$stmt->execute();
```